# A claim about the optimality of Van der Corput's lemma.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda > 0$.

This question concerns a statement made in the book Elias Stein, Harmonic Analysis: Real-variable Methods, Orthogonality and Oscillatory Integrals. Princeton University Press, 1993.

The statement is in Chapter 8, Section 1.2, on page 332.

**Here is the statement:**

Suppose we know only that $$|\phi^{(k)}(x)| \geq 1$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, where $k$ is some fixed positive integer. We wish to obtain an estimate for 
$$
\int_{a}^{b} e^{i \lambda \phi(x)} dx
$$
that is independent of $a$ and $b$. The change of variable $x \mapsto \lambda^{-1/k} x'$ shows that the only possible estimate for the integral is 
$$
O(\lambda^{-1/k}).
$$

**My question is:** How? How does this change of variable show that?

**Attempt:**

With the change of variable, the integral becomes 
$$
\int_{\lambda^{1/k}a}^{\lambda^{1/k}b} e^{i \lambda \phi(\lambda^{-1/k} x')} \lambda^{-1/k}dx' = \lambda^{-1/k} \int_{\lambda^{1/k}a}^{\lambda^{1/k}b} e^{i \lambda \phi(\lambda^{-1/k} x')} dx'
$$
Let $c = \lambda^{1/k}a$ and $d = \lambda^{1/k}b$. Let $f(x) = \lambda \phi(\lambda^{-1/k} x)$. Then $f^{(k)}(x) = \phi^{(k)}(\lambda^{-1/k}x)$, and so
$$
|f^{(k)}(x)| \geq 1
$$
for all $x \in [c,d]$. And the integral becomes
$$
\int_{c}^{d} e^{i f(x')} dx'.
$$
But what I am supposed to do with this?